# Using AngularJS select ng-options with Semantic UI's dropdown

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

So Semantic UI appears to the latest 'hot' UI framework which I'm impressed with; however, their dropdown isn't an implementation of the HTML 'select' and 'option' tags but instead custom. For my project, I'm using AngularJS which is phenomenal JavaScript MVW framework.

How can I integrate [AngularJS select ng-option](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) with [Semantic UI's dropdown](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html)? I'm not much of a JS pro. Here's the JSfidde: http://jsfiddle.net/fMUy3/

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App">

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <h3>Option 1 (standard)</h3>

        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="c as (c.id + ' - ' + c.name) for c in containers">
            <option value="">-- Pick A Container --</option>
        </select>
        <br>ID: {{selectedItem.id}}
        <br>Name: {{selectedItem.name}}
         <h3><a href="http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html"> Semantic UI Dropdown</a></h3>

        <div class="ui selection dropdown ">
            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="0">
            <div class="text">-- Pick A Container --</div>  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>   
            <div class="menu transition hidden">
                <div class="item active">-- Pick A Container --</div>
                <div data-value="{{container.id}}" class="item" ng-repeat="container in containers">{{container.name}}</div>
            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.containers = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Box1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Box2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Box3'}];

  //$scope.selectedItem = $scope.containers[0];
});

$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is you need to include semantic.js **after** jquery.

Second, you can't use `ng-options` on a div repeater but you *can* simulate it by using a `ng-click`

HTML

```
 <div data-value="{{container.id}}" class="item" ng-repeat="container in containers" ng-click="select(container)">
     {{container.name}}
 </div>
```

JS

```
$scope.select = function(container) {
    $scope.selectedItem = container;        
};
```

see [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/douglasg14b/6V66F/251/)

Comment: Thank you! Your fiddle works as expected. However, when I port it into my project, it doesn't work :-(.. specifically, the drop-down expands, but clicking on a values doesn't cause the list to close and show the selected item..`-- debug non working ver
div.ui "Determining whether event occurred in dropdown" [div.item] 0
div.ui "Event occurred in dropdown, canceling callback" [] 1
div.ui "Determining whether event occurred in dropdown" [div.item] 5

-- debug working ver
div.ui "Determining action" ["activate"] 0
div.ui "Triggering preset action" ["activate", "Box2", 2] 0`

Comment: @user1322092 Did you figure out why the clicking stopped working?

Comment: No, I've since moved onto using bootstrap which overall works betters and has supported angularjs plugins... semantic ui doesn't work well with angularjs

Comment: The resource links on your fiddle broke. Here is an updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/douglasg14b/6V66F/251/

Answer (score 7):

There were a few things wrong with your fiddle.  The first was that the semantic-ui JavaScript was being loaded before jQuery.  It depends on jQuery so jQuery must be loaded first.  (Also, loading jQuery before AngularJS is recommended.)

The second thing is that the semantic dropdown function was being called before AngularJS had a chance to unroll the repeater that creates the options.  This means the options were not there when semantic did its dropdown thing.  *As a **simple** solution* I made a timeout that would fire on the next processing loop; after AngularJS has done its thing.  You can see that semantic dropdown now works

This is more of a **simple** proof of concept to demo the timing of things and should not be used.
http://jsfiddle.net/fMUy3/1/

```
$timeout(function(){
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
},0)
```

How this **should** be handled is with a directive that will take care of the timings so that you do not need to use the timeout and would not need to specify each dropdown in the controller.  Here is the example using a directive (which would handle all cases)

http://jsfiddle.net/fMUy3/7/

```
app.directive('dropdown', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $(elm).dropdown().dropdown('setting', {
                    onChange: function (value) {
                        scope.$parent[attr.ngModel] = value;
                        scope.$parent.$apply();
                    }
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks TheSharpieOne... Chris' solution appears to work in the fiddle (although it doesn't work in my project - something I need to look into). I posted the console debug output under Chris' response in case you had any thoughts.

Comment: His is not done the angular way. Since the question is marked as as answered you may want to open a new one under jQuery and semantic ui